# C#, How to change the data type while reading in Ace.OleDB

Tags: c#, .net, excel, oledb

I need to read a Excel file that contains some blank cells and some cells with more than 255 characters in the same column, i tried to change the registry value "TypeGuessRows" to '0' and it worked, but i can't change the registry on the server.

here is my connection string:

```
StrConnXLS = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + SFileXLS + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=YES;MAXSCANROWS=0;'";
```

and i read the table by passing it to a data table like this:

```
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + tabela + "]", con))
                {


                    con.Open();

                    //conn.Open();
                    //Executando o UPDATE
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    OleDbDataAdapter oleAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                    oleAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    planilha = new DataTable("");
                    oleAdapter.FillSchema(planilha, SchemaType.Source);
                    oleAdapter.Fill(planilha);
                    //Fechando a conexão
                    con.Close();
                }
```

and i read it like:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in planilha.Rows)
 {
    string dostuff = row["test"].ToString();
 }
```

but every time it gets to the text with more than 255 characteres it cuts the text.
is that any way to change it?

Answer (score 1):

I've never found one. It's a real nuisance actually. OLEDB scans the first 8 rows regardless and makes assumptions about the data types.

IMEX=1 (not YES incidentally) forces any mixed rows it finds to text.

To the best of my knowledge ImportMixedTypes, TypeGuessRows and MaxScanRow in the connection string are ignored by this driver. The older Jet driver supported them. This is a retrograde step in my opinion.

If your file has a header row you could try HDR=No which would force it to text as the first row would be text but I don't think this will help your 255 Character limit problem.

You could try to target each cell using

```
SELECT * FROM [<SheetName>$<optional range>]
```

E.g. SELECT * FROM [MySheet$A1:A1]

But this will be very slow on a large file.